# Can I force Windows 10 to always boot in diagnostic mode?

Tags: drivers, display, safe-mode, diagnostic

I'm using an ASUS touch-screen monitor connected to a Windows 10 PC. Everything works, except that, every 1-2 minutes, the touch screen blacks out for about 3 seconds, then comes back. I've spent nearly 30 hours trying to diagnose and fix the problem, with no luck. Here's what I've tried:

1. Replaced *every* part of the system, one component at a time. The monitor, the entire PC, cables, keyboards, you name it.
2. Updating GPU driver
3. Rolling back GPU driver
4. Updating monitor driver (can't be done—the manufacturer product page says "we don't offer any drivers for this product")

The only thing I've found that has worked is starting the PC in diagnostic mode. This stops the flickering, but obviously it's not a great long term solution because the "start in diagnostic mod" setting isn't permanent, you have to manually set that option every time you shut down or restart.

Is it possible to force Windows to always start in diagnostic mode? I know that this stops many processes from running, that is perfectly ok for my needs.

Comment: While in diagnostic mode can you display and provide use the BCD for the system?

Comment: @Ramhound I would be happy to, but I don't know how to do that.